How do I use dynamically allocated array in different functions?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readingfromFile(const char *file_name) {
    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return -5;
    }
    int count = -8;
    int number;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &number) == 1) { //Scanning to find amount of numbers
        if (count < 0 ){ 
            count = 0;
        }
        ++count;
    }
    if (count == -8) { //To track empty file situation
        return -3;
    }  
    int i = 0;
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &number) != EOF) { //Writing numbers in array
        array[i] = number;
        ++i;
    }
    for (int d = 0; d < count; ++d) { //printing array
        printf("%d ", array[d]);
    }
    
    return 0;    
}

int findingLowestNumber(int *array, int size) {
    int minimum = array[0];
    for (int h = 1; h < size; ++h) { // finding minimum
        if (array[h] < minimum) {
            minimum = array[h];
        }
    }
    int newSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //deleting all aqurencies of minimum 
        if (array[i] != minimum) {
            array[newSize] = array[i];
            newSize++;
        }
    }
    
    for (int d = 0; d < newSize; ++d) { //printing edited array
        printf("%d ", array[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int res = readingfromFile("1.txt");
    if (res == -3) {
        printf("Empty file\n");
    }
    if (res == -5) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }
    findingLowestNumber(array[], count);
    return 0;
}

Here I have a code, which scans numbers from file in an array, then deletes all minimum numbers. I need to do it in 2 functions, first scans file and writes numbers in array, second deletes minimum numbers. How do I do it while allocating memory dynamically? And which arguments I need to pass to every function?

"How do I do it while allocating memory dynamically?" - You are already allocating memory dynamically. What seems to be the problem with the approach you use now?

There are 3 solutions:

you can use global variables;
you can pass pointers to your array and its size as arguments;
you can return your array and its size as fields of a struct.

Use global variables
It is as simple as writing:
int *array, size;

before your functions.
You can make it thread-safe with thread_local and hide it to other files of your project with static:
static thread_local int *array, size;

Using a global variable is not recommended because it can make it complicated to understand the purpose of your array, but it is a simple working solution for very small projects.
Pass pointers as arguments
As your functions already return another value, you can choose to pass a pointer to your array as argument, and same for the size:
int readFromFile(const char *filename, int **array, int *size)
/* ... */

int removeLeast(int **array, int *size)
/* ... */

int main(void)
{
    int *array, size;
    int res = readFromFile("1.txt", &array, &size);
    /* ... */
    removeLeast(&array, &size);
    /* ... */
}

Then, in your two functions, you will have to write the two variables with an asterisk each time:
*array = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
*size = count;
(*array)[i] = number;
...

A better solution is certainly to put the two variables into a struct. For example, using Slice from my small library HandyMacros:
#include <handymacros.h>

DeclareSlice(int)
// This is equivalent to:
typedef struct Slice(int) {
    size_t len;
    int *data;
} Slice(int);

int readFromFile(const char *filename, Slice(int) *array)
{
    /* ... */
    *array = slice_new(int, count);
    /* ... */
        array->data[i] = number;
    /* ... */
}

/* ... */

int main(void)
{
    Slice(int) array;
    int res = readFromFile("1.txt", &array);
    /* ... */
}

I think this is the best option for your case.
Return a struct
typedef struct {
    int res;
    int *array, size;
} ResIntArray;

ResIntArray readFromFile(const char *filename)
{
    /* ... */
        return (ResIntArray){ .res = -3 };
    /* ... */
    return (ResIntArray){ .array = array, .size = size };
}

ResIntArray removeLeast(int *array, int size)
{
    /* ... */
    return (ResIntArray){ .array = array, .size = size };
}

int main(void)
{
    ResIntArray resArray = readFromFile("1.txt");
    if (resArray.res == -3)
    /* ... */
    resArray = removeLeast(resArray.array, resArray.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < resArray.size; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", resArray.array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


thread_local won't work in case one thread allocates the data then intends to use a global to pass along that data to another thread. Which perhaps is a likely scenario.

simply pass the size of the array and the pointer to the other function.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int readingfromFile(const char*file_name, int **array, size_t *size)
{
    FILE*file=fopen(file_name,"r");
    if(file==NULL){
        return -5;
    }
    size_t count=SIZE_MAX;
    int number;
    while(fscanf(file,"%d",&number)==1){ //Scaning to find amount of numbers
        if(count == SIZE_MAX){ 
            count=0;
        }
        ++count;
    }
    if(count==SIZE_MAX){ //To track empty file situation

        return -3;
    }  

    size_t i=0;
    *array = malloc(sizeof(**array)*count);
    if(!*array) return ENOMEM;
    while(fscanf(file,"%d",&number)!=EOF){ //Writing numbers in array
        (*array)[i]=number;
        ++i;
    }
    for(size_t d=0;d<count;++d){ //printing array
        printf("%d ",(*array)[d]);
    }
    
    *size = count;
    return 0;
    
}
int findingLowestNumber(int *array,size_t size){
    int minimum=array[0];
    for(size_t h=1;h<size;++h){ // finding minimum
        if(array[h]<minimum){
            minimum=array[h];
        }
    }
    size_t newSize = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) { //deleting all aqurencies of minimum 
        if(array[i] != minimum) {
            array[newSize] = array[i];
            newSize++;
        }
    }
    
    for(size_t d=0;d<newSize;++d){ //printing edited array
        printf("%d ",array[d]);
    }
    return 0;
} 
int main(void)
{
    size_t count;
    int *array;
    int res=readingfromFile("1.txt", & array, &count);
    if(res==-3){
        printf("Empty file\n");
    }
    if(res==-5){
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }
    if(res == 0) findingLowestNumber(array, count);
    return 0;
}

use size_t for sizes and indexes
